# Displaying a default image in gridview

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview

How to display a defualt profile image in gridview if user didn't provided any image.

```
if (fileUpload.PostedFile == null) 
{ 
    lblStatus.Text = "No file specified."; 
    return; 
} 
else
{        
{
```

Comment: Please post an example of the code you are using now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach might be to check each row during RowDataBound event to see image exists or not. If it is empty, you can assign a default image url.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{        
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image image= (Image)e.Row.FindControl("ImageForPerson");

        if (image != null && image.ImageIrl == "")
        {
            image.ImageUrl = // default image url goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add RowDataBound event to your GridView definition.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" />
```

---

Or If you do not want to use RowDataBound event. At Page_Load you can manually go through each Row of GridView and check ImageUrl one by one.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach(GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
     {
         Image image = (Image)gvr.FindControl("ImageForPerson");

         if (image != null && image.ImageIrl == "")
         {
             image.ImageUrl = // default image url goes here
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: em using asp upload control and inserting the image into database and if user doesn't provide image it inserts null value into database table.. instead i want to show a defualt image, when user didn't provided.

Comment: okey I think my solution should work for you. When you are binding the GridView the image url will be null since the user did not provide any. However, as I said you can check it at RowDataBound event and if it is null, you can give it a default url to show.

Comment: "if (fileUpload.PostedFile == null)           
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "No file specified.";
            return;
        }
        else
        {"  how can i call that event in this scenario

Comment: thanks, THE CODE SNIPPET working fine just wanted to know why getting this error when i use Page_Load event.
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' because 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: you are welcome. I forgot the put .Rows that is why you were getting that exception. see my updated foreach statement.

Comment: I want to see my question without that -1 anybody.. its been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done in a single line in the aspx itself. By using a ternary operator.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("userImage").ToString()) ? "/images/" + Eval("userImage") : "/images/noimage.jpg" %>' />
```