# Display default img in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

*I'm making a list of all my users in a gridview*, which I will show a default image for those who do not have a profile picture.

**I have looked at this solution, but I can not get it to work**, what am I doing wrong.

[Displaying a default  image in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161610/displaying-a-default-image-in-gridview?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

*My code Gridview control*

```
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlListeOverBruger" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gwListeOverBruger" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" OnRowDataBound="gwListeOverBruger_RowDataBound" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="fldId">
            <Columns>
                <%-- profil billede --%>
                <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Billede" SortExpression="fldBrugernavn">
                    <ItemTemplate>                           
                     <asp:Image ID="img" ImageUrl='../img/profil/<%#Eval("fldImg") %>' runat="server" style='width: 100px; overflow: hidden;'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <%-- brugernavn --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Brugernavn" SortExpression="fldBrugernavn">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBrugernavn" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldBrugernavn") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBrugernavn" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldBrugernavn") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <%-- Email --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="fldEmail">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmail") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmail") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <%-- bruger rolle --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bruger rolle" SortExpression="fldRolle">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBrugerRolle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldRolle") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBrugerRolle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldRolle") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <%-- Slette knappen --%>
                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Handling" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-danger" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBcmsListeOverBruger %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM CmsBrugere WHERE (fldId = @original_fldId) AND (fldRolle_fk &gt; '1')" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [CmsBrugere] ([fldBrugernavn]) VALUES (@fldBrugernavn)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT CmsBrugere.fldId, CmsBrugere.fldImg, CmsBrugere.fldBrugernavn, CmsBrugere.fldEmail, CmsBrugerRoller.fldBrugerId_fk, CmsBrugerRoller.fldRolle FROM CmsBrugere LEFT OUTER JOIN CmsBrugerRoller ON CmsBrugerRoller.fldId = CmsBrugere.fldRolle_fk" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [CmsBrugere] SET [fldBrugernavn] = @fldBrugernavn WHERE [fldId] = @original_fldId">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldId" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="fldBrugernavn" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="fldBrugernavn" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldId" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </asp:Panel>
```

*Codebehind Pageload*:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {


        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gwListeOverBruger.Rows)
        {
            Image image = (Image)gvr.FindControl("img");

            if (image != null && image.ImageUrl == "")
            {
                image.ImageUrl = "../img/profil/default-billede/ingen-profil-billede.png";
            }




        }
    }
}
```

*Codebehind OnRowDataBound*:

```
 protected void gwListeOverBruger_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image profilImg = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("img");

        if (profilImg != null && profilImg.ImageUrl == "")
        {
            profilImg.ImageUrl = "../img/profil/default-billede/ingen-profil-billede.png";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ternary operator in the Image Control itself to check if there is an image and if not display a default one.

```
<asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("fldImg").ToString()) ? "../img/profil/" + Eval("fldImg") : "../img/profil/default-billede/ingen-profil-billede.png" %>' />
```